# Why $g(a,b) = \|a-b\|$ is continuous?

Tags: analysis

$X$ is a subset of cartesian coordinate space, and assume $f: X \rightarrow X$ satisfies $x, y \in X, x \neq y \Rightarrow \|f(x) - f(y)\| \lt \|x-y\|$.

I found a statement that if X is a compact set, and $g: X \times X \rightarrow \mathbb R$ s.t. $g(a,b) = \|a-b\|$ for $(a,b) \in X \times X$, function $g$ is a continuous function.

But, I don't understand why $g$ can be a continuous function.

My abstract thought is that it is related with the fact that $\vert \|a-b\| - \|c-d\| \vert \le \|(a-b) - (c-d)\| = g(a-c,b-d)$, but I can't proceed it more.

Help me please.

Answer (score 1):

For continuity of f you want to show (per definition), that for every $\epsilon>0$ you can find a $\delta>0$ such that ||x-y||$<\delta\Rightarrow$ ||f(x)-f(y)||$<\epsilon$.
By your inequality, choosing $\epsilon=\delta$ works for every $\epsilon$.

By the same argument: f(x)=||x|| is continuous. Since the composition of continuous functions is itself continuous, it remains to show, that vector substraction is continuous. This is discussed, for example here: [Proof that every normed vector space is a topological vector space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167890/proof-that-every-normed-vector-space-is-a-topological-vector-space)
.

Comment: Do you mean that distance between $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ is just same as $||(a-b) - (c-d)|| = ||(a-c) - (b-d)||$ ?

Comment: I thought you wanted to show, that f as a above has to be continuous. Rereading your question seems to indicates something else, although i'm not quite sure what the f has to do with the rest of the question.

Comment: So you only care about the continouity of g?

Comment: Actually the original question was proving $f$ has a fixed point if $X$ is a compact set. But, I have already found several solutions about this problem. Function $g$ was mentioned among those solutions, and what I want to know is why they are saying $g$ is continuous function. Sorry for writing question confusing.