# Show that $\mathbb{R} \times X \to X: (\lambda, x ) \mapsto \lambda x$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

I'm proving that on a normed space $(X, \Vert.\Vert)$, the function $\mathbb{R} \times X  \to X: (\lambda, x ) \mapsto \lambda x$ is continuous on its domain, where the domain is equiped with the maximum norm $d_M((a,x),(b,y)) = \max\{|a-b|,\Vert y - x \Vert\}$

I fixed a point $(\lambda_0,x_0)$. I have to prove that:

$$\forall \epsilon > 0: \exists \delta > 0: \forall (\lambda, x) \in \mathbb{R}\times X: \max\{|\lambda- \lambda_0|, \Vert x - x_0\Vert \} < \delta \implies \Vert\lambda x - \lambda_0 x_0\Vert < \epsilon$$

I did the following:

$$\Vert \lambda x - \lambda_0 x_0\Vert \leq (|\lambda - \lambda_0| + |\lambda_0|)\Vert x - x_0\Vert + \Vert x_0\Vert |\lambda - \lambda_0| < (\delta+ |\lambda_0|)\delta + \Vert x_0 \Vert \delta$$

Can I choose $$\delta := \min\left\{\sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}, \frac{\epsilon}{2(|\lambda_0| + \Vert x_0 \Vert + 1)}\right\}$$

to make the expression smaller than $\epsilon$?

Comment: This is a specific question about how to pick the appropriate delta, which none of the answers in that post adress...

Comment: My apologies, I actually meant to link to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167890/proof-that-every-normed-vector-space-is-a-topological-vector-space). Somehow I messed that up, I'll retract.

Comment: Let me edit this post so nobody will say it is a duplicate...

Comment: I don't get this. People want to close this while I ask whether a particular delta would work in MY proof. I'm not following anyone's else solution? Just makes me think the reviewers are just brainlessly marking things as duplicates while not even reading what's written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $\delta < \min(1, \frac{\epsilon}{3},\frac{\epsilon/3}{|\lambda_0|}, \frac{\epsilon/3}{\|x_0\|})$. (Be careful if $\lambda_0=0$ or $\|x_0\|=0$.) Then

$$\delta^2+|\lambda_0|\delta+\|x_0\|\delta < \frac{\epsilon}{3}\cdot1+|\lambda_0|\cdot\frac{\epsilon/3}{|\lambda_0|}+\|x_0\| \cdot \frac{\epsilon/3}{\|x_0\|}= \frac{\epsilon}{3}+\frac{\epsilon}{3}+\frac{\epsilon}{3} = \epsilon.$$

In general, when you are finding a value of $\delta$ to make an expression less than $\epsilon$, you don't have to solve for $\delta$ exactly. What I did above was to make $\delta$ less than several different quantities, because I wanted to use different bounds in different places.

Comment: How about adding + 1 in the denumerators to not worry about the cases $\lambda_0 = 0$ and $x_0 = 0$?

Comment: I did something analoguous and I would take $\delta := \min\left\{\frac{\epsilon}{3 (\Vert x_0 \Vert +1)},\frac{\epsilon}{3 (\vert \lambda_0 \vert +1)} ,  \sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{3}}\right\}$. Is this correct?

Comment: Sure, that would work.

Comment: One last question: would $$\delta := \min\left\{\sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}, \frac{\epsilon}{2(|\lambda_0| + \Vert x_0 \Vert + 1)}\right\}$$ work too?

Comment: Yes, I think that would also work. There's no need to go searching for the "best" $\delta$, though. If you have one that works, that's all you need.

Comment: Okay thank you for all your help! Curious who downvoted you without any reason though.

Comment: Let fix $\lambda$ and $ x$  s.t, $\|x-x_0\|<1 $ then, $\|x\| \le \|x-x_0\|+\|x_0\|\le \|x_0\|+1$ $$\|\lambda x -\lambda_0x_0\| = \|\lambda x -\lambda_0 x+\lambda_0 x-\lambda_0x_0\| \\\le \|x\||\lambda -\lambda_0| +|\lambda_0| \|x-x_0\|\\ < (\|x_0\|+1)|\lambda -\lambda_0| +(|\lambda_0|+1) \|x-x_0\|\\\le 2\max\left[(\|x_0\|+1),(|\lambda_0|+1)\right]\color{red}{\max\left[|\lambda -\lambda_0| , \|x-x_0\|\right]} $$ take $\color{red}{\delta= \min\left(1, \frac{\varepsilon}{ 2\max(\|x_0\|+1),(|\lambda_0|+1)}\right)}$